# How to naming correct Package name?

Tags: android, adt

I already read,
-> Creating an Android Project ( http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html )
-> Unique Package Names ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#d5e6484 )

I have a domain name "280w.info". and I just start Android programming.

1. I think that Package name is "info._280w.(project)" . so, I created "info._280w.Utest".
2. Click "Debug Test" as Android Application. lunch Android Emulator.
3. Console with error `[2013-04-16 21:52:26 - Utest] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!`
4. I checked logcat. and found error.
   `04-16 12:52:37.273: E/PackageParser(505): parsePackageLite error: <manifest> specifies bad package name "info._280w.utest": bad character '_'`
5. next, I view PackageParser.java ( /platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java ).
6. I found validation code. `if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {` at line 767.

Is this code wrong to Java's Unique Package Names rule?
or, Do I guess wrong package naming?

Comment: Fine seeing someone using the specs. Though underscore is the official solution, the tooling for Android falls short. Use `info.xxcccw` (latin numbering).

Comment: Thanks for comments. Okay, I'll use lowercase alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Use any package name recognized by Android.

Refer to the Android basics,

> it's **generally** best if you use a name that begins with the reverse domain name of your organization or publisher entity

and the Java documentation,

> In some cases, the Internet domain name may not be a valid package name. Here are some **suggested** conventions for dealing with these situations:
>   (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

they are just suggestions, not strict rules nor specifications.

Actually, there are bunch of apps which have the package name *not starting with reverse domain name* released on the Play Store. There is no domain part check, either Android and Google Play Store only check *whole* package name so hardly ever have namespace getting conflicted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the underscore but im not sure you can try: info.280w.projectname instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try Package Name is "info.280w.projectname", but it can not create project. -> '280w' is not a valid Java identifier.

Comment: Ok well thats not what i expected maybe you can try: info.two80w.projectname instead, its not important that your domain name is equals to the packagename prefix. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I think If Other people will get two80w.info, It'll be duplicate. Is it safe to naming to Package name?

Comment: If the package name is not entirely the same i dont think it will interfere, lets say you name your app: info.two80w.info.app and the others name it info.two80w.info.otherapp then it doesnt matter.

Comment: Sure i hoped you could understand my crappy english.